D-Link USB network adapter install
I am trying to install  D-Link USB to RJ45 dongle. When I unzip and try to make the file it has errors. D-Link 1312 USB dongle.
attb@Server1:~$ cd /home/mattb/Downloads/DUB-1312_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.14.3_SOURCE/
mattb@Server1:~/Downloads/DUB-1312_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.14.3_SOURCE$ make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
mattb@Server1:~/Downloads/DUB-1312_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.14.3_SOURCE$ sudo make
[sudo] password for mattb: 
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
mattb@Server1:~/Downloads/DUB-1312_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.14.3_SOURCE$ sudo modprobe
modprobe: ERROR: missing parameters. See -h.
mattb@Server1:~/Downloads/DUB-1312_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.14.3_SOURCE$ ls
DUB-13x2_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.14.3_SOURCE
mattb@Server1:~/Downloads/DUB-1312_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.14.3_SOURCE$ cd
mattb@Server1:~$ cd /home/mattb/Do
Documents/ Downloads/ 
mattb@Server1:~$ cd /home/mattb/Downloads/DUB-1312_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.14.3_SOURCE/DUB-13x2_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.14.3_SOURCE/
mattb@Server1:~/Downloads/DUB-1312_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.14.3_SOURCE/DUB-13x2_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.14.3_SOURCE$ make
make -C /lib/modules/6.8.0-39-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/mattb/Downloads/DUB-1312_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.14.3_SOURCE/DUB-13x2_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.14.3_SOURCE modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.0-39-generic'
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4398’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4401’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4404’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4407’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4410’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4413’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4416’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4419’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4422’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4425’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4428’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4431’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4434’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4437’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4440’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4443’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4446’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4449’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4452’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4455’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4458’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4461’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4464’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4468’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4471’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4474’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4477’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4480’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4483’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4486’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4489’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4492’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4495’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4498’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4505’: Permission denied
  SYNC    include/config/auto.conf.cmd
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4525’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4528’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4531’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4534’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4537’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4540’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4543’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4546’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘.tmp_4552’: Permission denied
  HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
scripts/basic/fixdep.c:445:1: fatal error: opening dependency file scripts/basic/.fixdep.d: Permission denied
  445 | }
      | ^
compilation terminated.
make[4]: *** [scripts/Makefile.host:116: scripts/basic/fixdep] Error 1
make[3]: *** [Makefile:628: scripts_basic] Error 2
/usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.0-39-generic/Makefile:770: include/config/auto.conf.cmd: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.0-39-generic/Makefile:793: include/config/auto.conf.cmd] Error 2
make[2]: *** [include/config/auto.conf.cmd] Deleting file 'include/generated/rustc_cfg'
make[2]: unlink: include/generated/rustc_cfg: Permission denied
make[2]: *** [include/config/auto.conf.cmd] Deleting file 'include/generated/autoconf.h'
make[2]: unlink: include/generated/autoconf.h: Permission denied
make[1]: *** [Makefile:240: __sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.8.0-39-generic'
mattb@Server1:~/Downloads/DUB-1312_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.14.3_SOURCE/DUB-13x2_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.14.3_SOURCE$ ^C


Some such dongles don't require a driver at all. They just work. Are you sure your effort is necessary?
